# Difference in sync call of async method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have synchronous code and I'm integrating with library that has only asynchronous methods.

What would be the best way to call asynchronous code from synchronous code and why:

I have two candidates:

**Solution A:**

```cs
var result = _service.CallAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

**Solution B:**

```cs
Task<string> task = Task.Run<string>(async () => await _service.CallAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
var result = task.Result
```

Which one is better and is `ConfigureAwait(false)` in solution B needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: Minor comment on code samples: semicolons are missing in the `result` declarations in both proposed solutions.

Comment: @MarcGravell ok but talking about facts, what is the difference between this one and solution B?

Answer (score 3):

Both A and B are inherently broken. They are both "sync over aysnc".

I suspect that B is *marginally less* broken, but... that's not a recommendation!

---

The only correct implementation is:

```cs
var result = await _service.CallAsync();
```

or if you don't need sync-context:

```cs
var result = await _service.CallAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For completeness: there *are* a few minor variants you could do based on this, for example checking for completion in a fast path to avoid state machine overheads in common paths, but: they would fundamentally still respect the async/await expectation.

Comment: ok and what if the project in which I'm using it is standard console app .net 4.5?

Comment: @Snorlax since .NET 4.5 was past end-of-life 4 years ago. The only advice I can give you with a clean conscience is "stop doing that". However, most async/await features should work well enough on .NET 4.5

Comment: Take a look at how Microsoft did it in c# 7.1: https://gunnarpeipman.com/csharp-async-main/
They added:

 [SpecialName]
        private static void <Main>(string[] args)
        {
            Program.Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

Comment: @Snorlax yes, I know; and that's a very specific context; it is viable *in that scenario* and there are no truly better options, but: that doesn't mean that you should emulate it in the general case

Comment: this is exactly the same thing. I have syncrhonous code in which I need to use code from asyncrhonous library. How I can do it in other way? I would have to rewrite the whole project just to call that method.

Comment: @Snorlax it isn't the same thing; there is a *very specific reason* why that exists on the process level - because the entry-point thread is the *definition* of the process lifetime. And yes, async is infectious - you can't just make one part async - it kinda needs to flow. If you want to *consume* async, the correct approach is to *be* async. Yes, that has a cost associated with it.  You *can* fake it with sync-over-async, but: it is very dangerous and scales very poorly; thus I can't *recommend* it. I also can't stop you from doing it.